# Pygame make sprite invisible/flashing while invincible

Tags: python, pygame

I have already implemented the invincibility / immunity part for when bullet collides with tank, now I want the sprite to "flash"/less opacity/invisible while immune. Here is the relevant code and TODOs where I want to implement a change in the tank image.

```
class Tank(GamePhysicsObject):
    # Handle respawn
    self.time_since_death       = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    self.immune                 = False
    self.immune_time            = 3000


def collision_bullet_tank(arb, space, data):
    # Set immunity, save time since death, start flashing
    tank.parent.immune = True
    tank.parent.time_since_death = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    tank.parent.start_flashing()


def post_update(self):

    # If tank has been immune for some time, make tank vulnerable again
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time - self.time_since_death > self.immune_time:
        self.immune = False
        # TODO: Stop flashing
```

Basically, my question is how can I make a visual sprite change?

Edit: More specifically, what do I type here?

```
def start_flashing(self):
    """ Call this function to make the tank flash. """
    #TODO: White layer opacity 50% ?
    1
```

Comment: You can use variables for flashing, e.g., `isFlashActive`, and sequentially set up their nature accordingly with a straight white color layer with opacity 100% for true and 0% for false values of the `isFlashActive`.

Comment: `isFlashActive`  is equivalent to `immune` of the Tank class. My question is how do I create a white color layer above the tank in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to draw the object `Tank` only in every 2nd frame as long as `self.immune` is set:

```py
class Tank(GamePhysicsObject):
    def __init__(self):
        self.immune = False
        self.frame_count = 0

    def draw(self)
        draw_tank = True
        if self.immune:
            self.frame_count += 1
            draw_tank = self.frameCount % 2 == 0
        if draw_tank:
            # draw the tank
```